# Usage of if, else, and else if

Tags: c++, if-statement

What is the difference between:

```
if      (expr1) {stmt}
else if (expr2) {stmt}
else if (expr3) {stmt}    
else            {stmt}
```

And the same code block written as:

```
if (expr1) {stmt}
if (expr2) {stmt}
if (expr3) {stmt}    
else       {stmt}
```

Comment: Homework?  Think logically about what else means, and what the difference should be.

Comment: I think one of the differences is in the error messages.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the first one, each block of statements is mutually exclusive; the structure guarantees that exactly one of them will get executed.

This is not true for the second one.  Consider:

```
if (a == 2) { /* blah */ }
if (a == 3) { /* blah */ }
if (a < 5)  { /* blah */ }
```

If `a == 2`, then **two** of the blocks will get executed.

Comment: Does that mean that in the first code block, say one of the if or else-if statement is true, the program will not check the rest of the if-else statements' conditions? I mean will it be logically equivalent to a sequence of switch cases, where each case is followed by a break statement?

Comment: One situatuation where you WANT to use a switch with multiple case/break but you CAN'T is when the case label is not a constant numeric but a variable or an object (like a string) so you must do if (s == "Hello") {...} else if (s == "Goodbye") {} else if (s == "Run") {...} else {...}

Answer (score 1):

Here's another good example to see how this works.

This example will print "FirstSecond":

```
if(1) {
    printf("First");
}
if(1) {
    print("Second");
}
```

This just prints "First":

```
if(1) {
    printf("First");
}
else if(1) {
    print("Second");
}
```

Comment: Oh this is a nice example! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your first code, at most ONE of the blocks can be executed.

In the second code, all of the blocks *could* be executed. (Except for the last else-thing.)

Comment: In the first case, *exactly* one will be executed. In the second, not all of the blocks could be executed. Exactly one of the last two are.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case exactly one of the blocks will be executed. In the second, the first and second blocks may or may not be executed and exactly one of the last two blocks will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

For the best performance choose a if else (if possible).

You can also use a switch case statement.

Answer (score 0):

For example if `condition1 == true` and `condition2 == true` the first block(else id) will execute only `some statements#1` and the second block would execute both `some statements#1` and `some statements#2`.
When you use else if the program would stop matching next conditions after first matched. It would be slightly faster on runtime if conditions are exclusive(i'm not sure if it's right word).

Answer (score 0):

With:

```
if      (expr1) {stmt1}
else if (expr2) {stmt2}
else if (expr3) {stmt3}    
else            {stmt4}
```

One and only *one* of the statements can be executed.

---

With:

```
if (expr1) {stmt}

if (expr2) {stmt}

if (expr3) {stmt}    
else       {stmt}
```

Either, both, or none of the first and second sections will be executed. In the last `if-else` section, either `stmt3` or `stmt4` will be executed.